# Read stream from CMOS Camera on arm linux and convert it to video / photo

Tags: java, linux, camera, embedded

I'm doing some stuff on an Arm linux device, specifically (FriendlyArm 2440).

I open the cmos camera (`"/dev/camera"`)

How can I convert it to a video / photo file?

my current code is like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
      String file = "/dev/camera";
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int count = fis.read(buffer);

      while (count != -1) {
        System.out.println(buffer);
        count = fis.read(buffer);
      } 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
      try {
        fis.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
```

Finally I want to send the data via socket to a client program on the PC and save the file over there or **just display the live stream**.

**What technique or library should I use to save as video /photo?**

Comment: you can convert it to a "hardware specific raw" video file by simply dumping the bytestream you read. If that does not suffice you, you must research what kind of video file you want and what codec for compression you want.

Comment: 1) Add a '?' to questions.  2) Leave out noise at the end of posts.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) package.  Not certain if your FriendlyArm 2440 board supports gstreamer, but you might be able to cross compile and add gstreamer yourself.  Then you can create a custom plugin to support your camera, then use the many available [plugins](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html) to generate/encode and stream video from the board... assuming you have the CPU resources.

You could also use gstreamer on the receiving PC side to receive and display or process the video/photos.  That might also be a possibility:  stream the raw video to the PC, and have the PC process it ( but that clearly requires more network bandwidth ).

Good luck,